# Daemon /etc/init.d message on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, daemon, init.d

When I start/stop/restart a daemon (eg. apache2), no message appears.
I am on Debian testing (jessie).

On my old server (Debian testing too), messages are displayed:

```
root@old-server # /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
[ ok ] Restarting web server: apache2.
```

But not on the new server:

```
root@new-server # /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

How could I do to view these messages?

The /etc/init.d/apache2 script (same on both servers): http://pastebin.com/RWHpSymG

Thank you!

Comment: That's odd. Can you post the script `/etc/init.d/apache2` in your question?

Comment: The script on the new server: http://pastebin.com/RWHpSymG

Comment: And on the old server: http://pastebin.com/8qWuGw4W

Comment: @Faheem, see my answer below, maybe you can add to it.

Comment: Please don't cross-post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193721/daemon-etc-init-d-message-on-debian This isn't a suitable question for SO anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions which provide the output are installed to the `/lib/lsb/init-functions.d` directory. Most likely you do not have anything there which provides the nice output.

The `lsb-base` package provides the `/lib/lsb/init-functions` script which is sourced by your init script. This provides stubs for the functions that produce the output which are overridden by sourcing each file in `/lib/lsb/init-functions.d`.

Scripts providing these functions should be put there by some package installed as part of your startup system. For example I have `systemd` on Debian Jessie which provides `/lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd`. This outputs a slightly different message when restarting services. For `ssh` I get:

```
[ ok ] Restarting ssh (via systemctl): ssh.service.
```

Most likely you either do not have the correct package installed, the files have somehow been deleted or there is a bug somewhere in the version of the package you are using.

Try doing `grep -r Restarting /lib/lsb` on both systems to find the file which produces the message (if there is one). You can then use `dpkg -S <filename>` to find the package that installed it.

Comment: `grep -R Restarting /lib` returns "/lib/init/init-d-script". But the `/lib/init/init-d-script` script is the same on both servers.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zueFGpb2

Comment: @Clément `/lib/init/init-d-script` isn't used by your init script as far as I can see. `/lib/lsb/init-functions` is sourced directly which should in turn source everything under `/lib/lsb/init-functions.d`. That is where the difference should be.

Comment: On the new server, there is a `40-systemd` additional file.
`dpkg -S 40-systemd` returns `systemd` but the package isn't installed on the old server.

Comment: @Clément, that sounds more like it. Debian Jessie is the first one to use `systemd` instead of the old `System V`. The idea of `systemd` is actually to move away from using shell scripts for services - you are supposed to use `systemctl` instead. Looking more closely at the `40-systemd` script, I see that it will actually call `systemctl` for you (hence the `via systemctl`) in some circumstances. Only then will it print a message, otherwise you get nothing. Note that `systemctl` itself does not print a message.

Comment: @Clément http://www.tecmint.com/systemd-replaces-init-in-linux/